# Swap two pickerviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I'm currently working on my first "big" project. The project is a simpel converter for different currencies. I wonder if it is possible to in some way invert the two arrays. I don't know how I should implement the if statement. Becouse if i put it in the title for row method i'm will probably get the control may reach non-void error message. I may explain this pretty bad but i just started programming.

```
if(!reverse) { // do nothing } else {
 // swap the two pickerviews 
 }


//Toggle reverse on/off <->
- (IBAction)Reverse:(id)sender {
reverse = (reverse+1)%2;
NSLog(@"%d",reverse);
}

//what title for row
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (component == 0) {
    return [Datarray objectAtIndex:row];
}
    return [Datarray2 objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do. Instead of having two or multiple PickerViews. Just change the DataSource and reload the PickerView. if you only have two currencies just use a flag, otherwise create a `NS_ENUM` to identify which array the PickerView DataSource should use and in the DataSource methods like, `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` use a switch case of `if-else statements` to identify the correct dataSource array.

```
// .h file
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, CURRENCY_TYPE) {
    CURRENCY_TYPE_US,
    CURRENCY_TYPE_DK
};

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArrayUS; // In this example, these arrays contains NSStrings
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArrayDK;
@property (nonatomic)         CURRENCY_TYPE currencyType;

// .m file
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
   switch (self.currencyType) {
    case CURRENCY_TYPE_US:
        return self.dataArrayUS[row];
        break;
    case CURRENCY_TYPE_DK:
        return self.dataArrayDK[row];
        break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)currencyChangingAction:(id)sender
{
    // Add some logic that changes to the self.currencyType to the correct currency.
    self.currencyType = CURRENCY_TYPE_US; // or _DK
    // And Reload Picker
}
```

EDITED:

Is this what you want? - This will only work if you have two Arrays though.

//what title for row

```
- (NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return (component == 0) ? [Datarray objectAtIndex:row] : [Datarray2 objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Comment: Finn larsen: otherwise create a NS_ENUM to identify which array the PickerView DataSource should use and in the DataSource methods like, pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent: use a switch case of if-else statements to identify the correct dataSource array. Could you explain abit more?

Comment: Thank you, not exactly what I was looking for but i will use it if i need it

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to achieve then? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time for that. But I think I might have misunderstood the question though. Is your problem that you're scared of reaching non-void in pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent: ?

Comment: fixed it:         if (reverse) {
          [Picker1 selectRow:row2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
        [Picker1 selectRow:row1 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
    } else {
        [Picker1 selectRow:row2 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
        [Picker1 selectRow:row1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    }